# How many weapons can I equip in A Dark Room?

Tags: a-dark-room

I'm trying to figure out the rules governing how well I can arm myself when venturing out.  I've been experimenting using trial and error, and I think I know the following:

- You're not limited by hands.  I've been able to have at least three weapons equipped at once (two different swords, plus a presumably-two-handed rifle.)
- You don't seem to be able to equip two of the same item.  I brought two steel swords with me, but didn't have a second attack option, like I did when I had one steel and one iron one. (It's possible having two made the reloading twice as fast, but that didn't seem to be the case.

Can anyone confirm whether the rule is in fact this:

**In any fight, you can use an unlimited number of unique weapons, but may not use more than one of any given one?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last I played, I could 'equip' as many unique weapons as I could carry. I could also use any and all of them during a fight as long as they had the necessary ammo.

However, having multiple quantities of the same weapon served no benefit and only made for excess weight.

Comment: Which is a bug, I guess?